# React Router Error: Invalid prop `component` supplied to `Route`

Tags: reactjs, react-router

When I run my app on the browser I get the following error in my console.

> Warning: Failed propType: Invalid prop 'component' supplied to 'Route'.

I'm currently using the versions of the following development requirements

`react v0.14.8
react-router v2.3.0
Webpack v1.13.0
babel-loader v6.2.4
babel-core v6.7.7
babel-preset-es2015 v6.6.0
babel-polyfill v6.7.4
babel-preset-react v6.5.0
babel-register v6.7.2
babel-runtime v6.6.1`

This is what my routes file looks like.

```
import {Route, IndexRoute} from '../node_modules/react-router';
import App from '../components/app';
import Dashboard from '../components/dashboard';
import UsersList from '../components/users/list';
import CoursesList from '../components/courses/list';

// Define routes

const routes = (
    <Route path='/' component={App}>
         <IndexRoute component={Dashboard}/>
         <Route path='/dashboard' component={Dashboard} />
         <Route path='/users' component={UsersList} />
         <Route path='/courses' component={CoursesList} />
    </Route>
);

export default routes;
```

An this is what my main js looks like

```
import React from './node_modules/react';
import ReactDOM from './node_modules/react-dom';
import {Router, browserHistory} from './node_modules/react-router';
import routes from './configs/routes';
// Render
ReactDOM.render(<Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes} />, document.getElementById("app") );
```

Please where could this error be coming from and how do I solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set up your router like

```
<Router history={browserHistory} >{routes}</Router>
```

instead of

```
<Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes} />
```

Comment: OMG, i updated my main js just as you said and found out that i wasn't exporting the App component, you just saved me, thanks a bunch,